# How to import a java project missing .project .settings .classpath files into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I got a java source code from an opensource project. The source code doesn't have eclipse project specific files such as .project ,.classpath ,.setting(directory). How can I import that java source into eclipse ?

---

I don't have pom.xml(mvn) file to specify. So I tried manually.

followed the below steps to solve

1. Create a directory with the projectName and a directory "src"  under projectName.
2. Move the source code ( ie: org/apache/hadoop directory) into src directory under projectName.
3. Create a sample project in eclipse and go the workspace and modify the .project xml file by changing the project name ,.settings ,.classpath files
4. Copy the modified ".project" file and ".settings" ,".classpath" from eclipse workspace project directory to the newly created directory "projectName/"
   5 .Use eclipse import option under File menu to import the newly created project use Existing project into workspace option
5. Give the project root directory as projectName directory.

Comment: Create a new Java project in Eclipse, Select c:\project as the root folder of the project (create a project from existing source)

Answer (score 9):

if you are using maven type `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on project folder

if you are not using maven, go to eclipse, import->import -> general -> filesystem (then select your directory with source files)

Comment: Especially check if the original project is *maven* (pom.xml) or similarly *ant* (build.xml) based. For maven install the maven plugin in eclipse.

Comment: thnx for the quick replay. But i dont have ny pom.xml files.

Answer (score 5):

If you doesn't have .project .classpath and .settings file, Representing the project isn't eclipse project, so you should create a standard eclipse project

you can following below step:

1. **copy your project or open source project into
   workspace.**
2. **window ->File ->New -> Java Project ->Project name input
   that just be copied project file name ->Finish**

Remember config your source code location:

**project ->Properties ->Java Build Path ->Source**

Answer (score 1):

If this is a maven project then you will not find these .project files. So instead of using import -> Existing project to Workspace use Existing Maven Project.

[image]

[image]