# Download ZIP file from GitHub and import in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, import, project

Why every project that I download as a zip file from Github i can't import in Eclipse?
This is how I try it...

1. Of course, firtst I download it as a ZIP. (download it to desctop, for example)
   [image]
2. Then, import existing project...
   [image]
3. **But then even if there is a project for sure**, and special this project, it shows me warning "No projects are found for import" like this:

[image]
This is problem for every project that I try to import like this. Is there any other way to import projects or...?
(I repet this project work 100% on my friends laptop, but I can't even import it)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have uncompress the zip archived first.

Then check the content of the folder where you uncompressed the zip file.
If there is no `.project` file, do create a new project in Eclipse, and point the sources to that folder, instead of trying to import it.
See "[How to import a java project missing .project .settings .classpath files into eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29392736/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can see the following:

- you have to select the folder where the project is created.
- you are sure that is a project, maybe are only the files

Pls attach the link of git to check this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same for GitHub download project. I figured out that if this is a maven project then you will not find these .project files. So instead of using import -> Existing project to Workspace use Existing Maven Project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I imported zip file in my STS , first of all i click on import project then click on **General** import some menu showed up [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs9Bw.png) , then click on **Projects from Folder or Archive** , then choose from Archive file click finish [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaTrJ.png)